# Search within a Hash containing hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have the following hash in Ruby :

```
{
    0 => {
        :method=>\"POST \",
        :path=>\"/api/online/platforms/fb/users/191023/add_infos\",
        :host=>\"host.12\",
        :duration=>\"1221\"
    },

    1 => { 
        :method=>\"GET \",
        :path=>\"/api/customer/191023/messages\",
        :host=>\"host.8\",
        :duration=>\"99\"
    }, 

    2 => {
        :method=>\"POST \",
        :path=>\"/logs/data\",
        :host=>\"host.10\",
        :duration=>\"142\"
    },

    3 => {
        :method=>\"POST \",
        :path=>\"/api/customer/191023\", 
        :host=>\"host.6\",
        :duration=>\"243\"
    }

    4 => {
        :method=>\"POST \",
        :path=>\"/api/customer/191023\", 
        :host=>\"host.2\",
        :duration=>\"132\"
    }
}
```

I would like to do a simple search within these hashes to find those whose the method key is set to `POST` and the path key set to `"/api/customer/191023"`. The equivalent of `data.where(method: "POST", path: "/api/customer/191023")`.

First, I've tried with a `select` only based on `method`:

```
 hs = hash.select{|k, h| h[:method] == "POST" }
```

But the returned hash is empty.

Thank you.

M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw what you have a space after the value of `:method` key, so try [regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp) to match it, like follows:

```
hs = hash.select {|k, h| h[:method] =~ /POST/ && h[:path] == '/api/customer/191023' }
```

To find host value with highest frequency do:

```
hs = hash.values.group_by { |h| h[:host] =~ /host\.(\d+)/ && $1.to_i || 0 }.to_a
hs.reduce([-1,0]) { |sum,v| v[1].size > sum[1] && [ v[0], v[1].size ] || sum }.first
```

Comment: Indeed my bad, my previous regex that generates the hash was wrong. Thank you !

Comment: Thank you, but what is the "v" variable? Is it a typo?