# Hash and frequency of a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have the following hash in Ruby :

```
{
    0 => {
        :method=> "POST",
        :path=> "/api/customer/191023", 
        :host=> "host.8",
        :duration=> "1221"
    },

    1 => { 
        :method=> "GET",
        :path=> "/api/customer/191023", 
        :host=> "host.8",
        :duration=> "99"
    }, 

    2 => {
        :method=> "POST",
        :path=> "/api/customer/191023", 
        :host=> "host.10",
        :duration=> "142"
    },

    3 => {
        :method=> "POST",
        :path=> "/api/customer/191023", 
        :host=> "host.8",
        :duration=> "243"
    }

    4 => {
        :method=> "POST",
        :path=> "/api/customer/191023", 
        :host=> "host.10",
        :duration=> "132"
    }
}
```

I would like to do a simple search within these hashes to find the `host` with the highest frequency. For example, in the previous example, I should get `host.8`.

Thank you for your help,

M.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search within a Hash containing hashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27126400/search-within-a-hash-containing-hashes)

Comment: You may wish to do an edit to correct the string formatting issue I mentioned in my answer. I expect that accounts for the downvote and votes to close.  I'll delete this comment once you've seen it--reply not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do that.

**Code**

```
def max_host(hash)
  hash.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(_,v),h| h[v[:host]] += 1 }
      .max_by { |_,v| v }
      .first
end
```

**Example**

Let's take the simplified example below. Note that I've changed, for example, `:host = \"host.10\"` to `:host = "host.10"`, as the former is not a correct syntax. You could write the string as `'\"host.10\"` (`=> "\\\"host.10\\\""`), but I assume you simply want `"host.10"`. The code is the same for both.

```
hash = {
    0 => {
      :method=>"POST",
      :host  =>"host.8"
    },

    1 => { 
      :method=>"GET",
      :host  =>"host.10"
    }, 

    2 => {
      :method=>"POST",
      :host  =>"host.10"
    }
}

max_host(hash) 
  #=> "host.10"
```

**Explanation**

For the example `hash` above,

```
enum = hash.each_with_object(Hash.new(0))
  #=> #<Enumerator: {
  #     0=>{:method=>"POST", :host=>"host.8"},
  #     1=>{:method=>"GET",  :host=>"host.10"},
  #     2=>{:method=>"POST", :host=>"host.10"}}:each_with_object({})>
```

The enumerator will invoke the method [Hash#each](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-each) to pass each element of the enumerator into the block. We can see what those elements are by converting the enumerator to an array:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[[0, {:method=>"POST", :host=>"host.8"}],  {}],
  #    [[1, {:method=>"GET",  :host=>"host.10"}], {}],
  #    [[2, {:method=>"POST", :host=>"host.10"}], {}]]
```

The empty hash shown in the first element is the initial value of the hash created by

```
Hash.new(0)
```

This creates a hash `h` with a default value of zero.  By doing it this way, if `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` will return the default value (`0`), but (important!) this does not change the hash.

The first value passed into the block is

```
[[0, {:method=>"POST", :host=>"host.8"}],  {}]
```

This is then decomposed (or "disambiguated") into individual objects that are assigned to  three block variables:

```
k => 0
v => {:method=>"POST", :host=>"host.8"}
h => Hash.new(0)
```

We then execute:

```
h[v[:host]] += 1
```

which is

```
h["host.8"] += 1
```

which is shorthand for

```
h["host.8"] = h["host.8"] + 1
```

[Aside: you may have noticed that in the code I show the block variables as `|(_,v),h|`, whereas above I refer to them above as `|(k,v),h|`. I could have used the latter, but since `k` is not reference in the block, I've chosen to replace it with a "placeholder" `_`. This ensures `k` won't be referenced and also tells any readers that I'm not using what would be the first block variable.]

As `h` does not have a key `"host.8"`, `h["host.8"]` to the right of `=` returns the default value:

```
h["host.8"] = 0 + 1
  #=> 1
```

so now

```
h #=> {"host.8"=>1}
```

The second element passed into the block is

```
[[1, {:method=>"GET",  :host=>"host.10"}], {"host.8"=>1}]
```

so the block variables become:

```
v => {:method=>"GET",  :host=>"host.10"}
h => {"host.8"=>1}
```

Notice that the hash `h` has been updated. We execute

```
h[v[:host]] += 1
  #=> h["host.10"] += 1
  #=> h["host.10"] = h["host.10"] + 1
  #=> h["host.10"] = 0 + 1
  #=> 1
```

so now

```
h #=> {"host.8"=>1, "host.10"=>1}
```

Lastly, the block variables are assigned the values

```
v = {:method=>"POST", :host=>"host.10"}
h => {"host.8"=>1, "host.10"=>1}
```

so

```
h[v[:host]] += 1
  #=> h["host.10"] += 1
  #=> h["host.10"] = h["host.10"] + 1
  #=> h["host.10"] = 1 + 1
  #=> 2

h #=> {"host.8"=>1, "host.10"=>2}
```

and the value of `h` is returned by the method.

Answer (score 2):

To find host value with highest frequency do:

```
hs = hash.values.group_by { |h| h[:host] =~ /host\.(\d+)/ && $1.to_i || 0 }.to_a
hs.reduce([-1,0]) { |sum,v| v[1].size > sum[1] && [ v[0], v[1].size ] || sum }.first
```

**Description:** `[-1,0]` is the default value for set for [`#reduce` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce), where `-1` is a number (like in `host.number`), and `0` is a count of the number. So, when reduce encounters the number with size more than of passed `sum`, it replaces with the new value on next iteration.

Comment: Thank you, but what is the "v" variable? Is it a typo?

Comment: Thank you, awesome. You are really helpful. I have some difficulties to understand the call to reduce, particularly the array [-1,0] passed as an argument and the check done on v and sum.

Comment: @Mich array of [-1,0] is default value for set; where -1 is a number (like host.number), and 0 is count of the number. when reduce encounters the number with size more than of passed sum, it replaces with the new value on next iteration.